# VBA automatization

Tags: vba, excel

I have some troubles with this part of my code and I'm sure there is a very simple way to sum up this action in one line

```
If Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 14).Value > 100000 _
And Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6) <> Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("B").Cells(2, 5) _
And Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6) <> Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("B").Cells(3, 5) _
And Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6) <> Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("B").Cells(4, 5) _
And Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6) <> Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("B").Cells(5, 5) _
And Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6) <> Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("B").Cells(6, 5) _
And Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6) <> Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("B").Cells(7, 5) _
And Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6) <> Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("B").Cells(8, 5) _
And Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6) <> Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("B").Cells(9, 5) _
And Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6) <> Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("B").Cells(10, 5) _
Then ...
```

The only variable that  changes is the row number at the end on each line
Thanks in advance for your help, I'm sure there is an easy way to automate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have an error in your code sample.
If you don't, then you are creating a bunch of And statements that look at multiple row,5 cells looking for a match.

In this case, each of those multiple row,5 cells would have to be equal and match the single (i, 6) value you are comparing.

If this code is correct, then you only have to do one check as if it passes or fails, so will all the other "And" lines.

Comment: You're right, I should have used "Or" instead. Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 2):

First I would use a with block to stop repetitive typing.  Then use Match() to see if the value exist in the range or not:

```
With Workbooks("A.xlsm")
If .Sheets("1").Cells(i, 14).Value > 100000 _
    And IsError(Application.Match(.Sheets("1").Cells(i, 6), .Sheets("B").Range(.Sheets("B").Cells(2, 5), .Sheets("B").Cells(10, 5)), 0)) Then

    'the rest of your code

End With
```

Comment: However if I open another Excel file in the same time, it doesn't work

Comment: @user6366207 it should as long as you put the `.` in front of every `Sheets("...` that is tied to the workbook stated in the `With Worbook("...`